# How to get components of a Tuple in C#?

Tags: c#

If I have a `Tuple<int, double>` declared, I would like to get the following.

1. An object, I would imagine that this is a type object, that I can perform comparison on, to the effect of `obj == typeof(Tuple<>)` and it would return `true`.
2. An array of Type objects, which is equivalent to `new[]{typeof(int), typeof(double)}`. This I can figure out with reflection, since the tuple object exposes it's items as Properties, but then I don't know the order of these properties and the MSDN article says I can't rely on observation...

I need this in order to make a special case for a generic method, which should do something special if it's passed a tuple. Like so:

```
void foo<T>(...){
    if(T == Tuple<Q, S, ...>){
     //special code that needs to know what Q and S and ... are.
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (typeof(T).IsGenericType && typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Tuple<,,>)) 
{
}
```

You must know the number of arguments for Tuple before-hand (in this case 3, so two commas).  In other words, Tuple<> is distinct from Tuple<,>, etc.   Once you know it's of the correct type, you may call:

```
typeof(T).GetGenericArguments()
```

Which returns an array of the type arguments passed to the Tuple.

Comment: Thank you very much. Shame that I have to know the number of arguments in advance though. I suppose there's no way around that?

Comment: Well, there are a finite number of Tuple permutations, so you can plan for them.  For example, you can store all 16 Types in an array and get the one that corresponds to the number of type arguments == GetGenericArguments().Length.